# What should I do about a question I posted that is not answered?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, not-an-answer

This question I asked (["How to deleting user data in Windows 7 on shutdown or start up”](https://superuser.com/q/982159/451966)) is not being answered. What should I do?

Comment: SU's purpose is to build a knowledgebase to help others with similar problems.  How to accomplish a specific, common task is useful to others.  You are probably the only one who needs the unique script you describe.  It's possible someone will see it as a fun challenge and dabble in a solution, but your question probably won't attract people rushing to answer.  Bumping won't matter.  You're better off reducing the request to a simple piece that's giving you the most problems, as a jump-start to your own solution.  Sorry, just realistic expectations.

Comment: @jo900 - If you want an answer you will have to give the community longer then a week to answer it.  Of course given how you simply are requesting a script, its unlikely you will get an answer, we are not a script concierge website.  Those of course exist so I suggest you go there if your not willing to even attempt to do this yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wait. Eventually someone will answer the question. There is also a system that automatically 'bumps' questions without answers to the front page after a certain amount of time.

We also have a section in the Help Center about this: https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers

Bumping questions is also frowned upon:
https://superuser.com/questions/986865/program-or-something-for-deleting-user-data-in-win-7
[How to deleting user data in Windows 7 on shutdown or start up](https://superuser.com/questions/982159/script-or-something-for-deleting-user-data-in-win-7)

Please don't post questions multiple times. You need to be patient. This is a free service where people choose to answer questions when they can.

As for the question itself? We're not a script writing service. We can help you with something you have already written that isn't working properly, but asking us to write it for you is not going to garner a lot of response.

Comment: A better question that may get more attention would most likely ask about problems with a non-working script, what files need to be deleted to clear user data, or possibly even just how to delete a file using scripts. (The last one was most likely already asked, and please do not ask existing questions.)